# Fread is not reading when structure is declare in heap section?

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread

Fread is not reading when structure is declare in heap section? I am able to write in file but when i try to read the file i am getting segmentation fault.My code is below please help me to fix?

Below first code is for writing structure data in a file and this structure is store in heap section and second code is for reading the contain of the file

**Writer Source**

```
/* writing in file this code is good*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct st
{
    int roll;
    char name[11];
    float marks;
};
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct st *var;
    var=malloc(sizeof(struct st) *5) ;

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ha","w");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("enter roll\n");
        scanf("%d",&var[i].roll);
        printf("enter name\n");
        scanf("%s",var[i].name);
        printf("enter marks\n");
        scanf("%f",&var[i].marks);

    }
    fwrite(&var,sizeof(struct st),1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

**Reader Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct st
{
    int roll;
    char name[11];
    float marks;
};
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct st *var1;

    var1=malloc(sizeof(struct st)*5);
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ha","r");
    fread(&var1,sizeof(struct st),1,fp);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)   // I M GETTING SEGMENTATION FAULT?
    {
        printf("%d\n",var1[i].roll);
        printf("%s\n",var1[i].name);
        printf("%f\n",var1[i].marks);
    }
}
```

Comment: fread(&var1,sizeof(struct st),1,fp); var1 here is already a pointer. Don't use & here. And read each struct in loop, you read just first item.

Answer (score 0):

You only allocated space for one `struct st` but you try to access 5 of them.

To allocate 5, do `var = malloc(5 * sizeof *var);`

Also, you open your file 5 times, the `fp=fopen("hai","w");` line should come after the loop. (And you should check if it succeeded).

Comment: i made changes u said but still segmentation fault.can u please edit my code and show?

Comment: No, that's not how this site works. Post the changes that you made. Also , debug your program. You should figure out which line the segfault occurs on, then that will give you a clue as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(fp == NULL)
{
    return 1;
}
```